# Disable ads after in-app product purchase with in-app billing 5

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have set up in-app billing 5 in my application which is mainly about disabling Admob ads after the user makes a purchases , after the user pays for the in-app product , I would like to know what are the possible ways to disable ads after the purchase is made , I have thought about using product flavors but not sure if it is the right approach to follow , on the other hand i'm not using any local or remote database to save the user product purchase details , i'm here seeking an advice from you and those who used in-app billing before for the same scenario , Thank you in advance

Comment: Post a successful purchase, store a boolean flag in a local storage (like DataStore) & use the same to either load or not load the Ads if purchased. On app startup, simply query the store for purchases & update the flag if there's a change.

Comment: Alright mate , Thank you , appreciate your answer

Comment: I would like to also ask about something , when user purchases a product , does it accredit that purchase to the user email , or all emails that are available in the user device ?

Comment: Only the current signed-in email. So the user needs to use the same email address in the future to access the purchased feature.